# Magento 2 knockout JS template for Product listing and detail page

Tags: magento-2.1, knockoutjs

I was wondering since knockout was introduced in magento 2 why this has not been implemented fully.

For example I see knockout been use only in checkout page.

Pages like product listing page, detail page why knockout has not been implemented? Is there any reason?

I want to implement knockout in listing and detail page with layer navigation. How to implement it in catalog pages?